# I have a button in layout, you can move to an actionbar?

Tags: button, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have a button on a layout, but I want this available on the actionbar, I tried to move it but it does not work, any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the button directly through the layout. 
Create instead a menu folder insede the res folder. And than add there an xml-file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" 
        android:title="@string/ac_rate" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ab_star"
        android:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

and call it from the code with something like:

```
    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.short_menu, menu);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this line I get error
getSupportMenuInflater();

I use to android studio